# Gated Assets - Auto-loading variable URL after Form Submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I have 5 buttons with direct download URLs to different assets (PDF and other file types).

I would like the user to click a button to download the asset, then be presented with a gated popup form, which must be filled out to access the asset URL.

Once the form is submitted, then onSubmit it automatically loads the asset URL.

How should I go about accomplishing this?

I'm using a Marketo form embedded into a webpage popup/modal.

I was using `data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"` to have the download buttons open the modal/popup when clicked, which works. My code looks like this:

```
<a href="https://example.com/download.pdf" onclick="VSCapture('Download PDF'); loadfile('https://example.com/download.pdf');" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" style="margin-bottom: 20px;">Download PDF</a>
```

How do I get the download to begin once the form is submitted rather than on click? I assume I need to pass the variable along, but I'm uncertain how to code this. Any thoughts? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you actually want this to be secured, you should really control this server-side. Don’t include the url to the pdf on the page, but instead have a form with a submit button. The form will post to the server, the server will validate the data that was posted, and if all seems well, will `redirect` the user to the url of the pdf. This design means that it’s impossible for the user to know the url to the pdf without submitting a valid form.

How you do a server side redirect will depend on your web framework. For example, if you’re using Ruby on Rails, you’d use the `redirect_to` method tell the client a URL to navigate to. Eg: `redirect_to('https://www.google.com')`

All in all, this will use a 302 status with a `Location` header of the URL, to tell the browser where to go next.

If you build the `<a>` tag like you have in your post, anyone could just right click and open your link in a new tab, bypassing your javascript form entirely. If you bake the url in a data attribute or your javascript file, it’ll be harder for normal people to figure out, but anyone who knows anything about web programming will still easily bypass it without filling out the form.

At the end of the day, you can only do so much to keep people honest. Ideally your server will build some kind of short lived URL each time, to make it hard for people to just paste a link around to each other. But if people want to steal, they’ll just share the pdf. Piracy is impossible to combat, but you can do your best to help honest people stay more honest by making it a little harder to cheat the system.